# Table design, with many attributes?

Tags: sql

I have a table called `people` and another called `people_attributes`.

On my site people submit a variety of attributes, like blue eyes, brown hair, thin and I need to return all unique people with the attributes.

Im struggling with my table design. One person in the `people` table can have many attributes. How should I save each person's attributes in the people table?

Or should I make a separate table with the type of attribute and the id of the person who has it?

But with this idea, an attribute can have many people, how can I store an attribute with many people attached to it but still only get out unique people? A comma delimitated list? But how would I search that? And how do I only return unique people?  I.E if I was searching for blue eyes and brown hair, the category blue eyes would have person 1 in it and so would brown hair. So the query would get back two person 1s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `People(id, name, etc.), Attributes(id, description), People_Attribute(people_id, attribute_id)`?

Comment: won't the people attribute table have lots of repeated data? So if person 1 has the attribute, tall, grey hair, blue eyes, wears glasses... wont that be 4 rows? Or are you able to put all attributes into one row?

Comment: Yes, they will have 4 rows... each of which is unique to that person. If you had all the data in one row, how would you search for all people with grey hair, who wear glasses, and are tall?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this, and it really depends on your needs.

**Easiest Possible way**

If you know, in advance, that the number of attributes isn't going to increase dramatically, and each attribute is going to have a few values, you could just have them in the same table.

```
Table People:
ID
Name
Eye_color
Weight
....
```

Benefits - Speed of reporting, easy to maintain.  Easy to understand queries
Downsides - inflexible.  Hard to add new columns, number of columns can get out of control.

**Separate Attributes Table**

In this case, you would have a separate attributes table, one row per person/attribute values.

```
Table People:
ID
Name

Table Attributes
ID
Name

Table Attributes_people
ID
People_ID
Attributes_id
Value
```

The queries might then look something like:

```
select * from people where id in (
  select people_id from attributes_people where value='blue' and attributes_id = 'eye color'
    intersect
  select people_id from attributes_people where value='brown' and attributes_id = 'hair color')
```

This would give you a list of all the people who had blue eyes and brown hair color

Benefits: Infinitely expandable, unlimited number of attributes per people.
Downside: Queries become more complicated to write.

**Object DB**

You could also look into a Object Oriented Databases such as MongoDB or CouchDB to store people as objects with as many attributes as you'd like.

Benefits: very flexible
Downside: Not SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can create tree tables:

1. people
2. Attribute_list
3. Peple_attribute

you can search in these table like:

```
select ... from people inner join Peple_attribute on ... inner join Attribute_list on ... Where  Peple_attribute.value='...' and Attribute_list.name='...'
```